# When does a (FUSE) filesystem check acces rights?

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, filesystems, fuse

"Unix world" filesystems (like ext4) store for each file, in the inode a list of permission/access rights for the 3 types of available users owner,group,other. 
**I want to know when the "authentication" happens;** what I mean is:

let's say we have a file

```
file.txt     rwx     rw-     ---       st_uid=54    st_gid=99
             owner   group   others
```

user `tim` having `uid=100`, `gid=99`

runs `cat file.txt` in the terminal, the request gets to the filesystem which compares `tim` to the permisions of the file;

`tim` is not the owner: his `uid=100` not the same with file's `uid=54`;

but he has the same gid as the file (`99`), so the response he gets is `rw-`

`cat` is actually a read so the user recieves the content

**In which system function is this scenario executed? Can I modify it by implementing a custom filesystem?**

**UPDATE:**
the sole purpose of my filesystem is to mess a little more with the permissions and be a proof of concept (it's a research project) so any ideas about where I should start would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Use the shell command `strace cat file.txt`, and you would discover for yourself that if there's an EACCES error, it happens as a result of the file **open()** syscall.

Comment: In terms of kernel architecture, I'd be surprised if fs modules have to do (implement) permissions checks themselves.  They probably return "mode bits" to the common fs routines in the kernel.  If you are looking to customize, check out ACL.

Comment: i'm creating a custom fuse filesystem and i can easily change the behavior of open/readdir/chmod..; my only problem is that even though i know all the details about the file, i don't know how to find out which user made the request; Any ideas ?

Comment: @sawdust `strace` seems a really good starting point; I wasn't aware of it's existence ;)

Comment: But does a filesystem really need to know which user is accessing the file? Let the kernel handle all the permission checking. Your FUSE filesystem should only be returning the data as stored in the filesystem.

Comment: @tangrs: i'm not sure if the filesystem should or sohuldn't know which user or process is accessing the files; but if the kernel is responsible for doing it, I would really like to know exactly where it happens; I'm ready to play with the kernel modules if that is necessary; thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is straight forward with respect to a FUSE filesystem: 
The FUSE implementation provides a **context** for each user request made to the filesystem;

The workflow looks like this:

1. A user makes a filesystem-related request (i.e. `ls`)
2. The kernel notices that that specific filesystem is mounted using FUSE
3. The request is forwarded to the custom filesystem (created using FUSE). Here you can access the request's metadata using [fuse_context](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/doxygen/structfuse__context.html) which will return a uid,gid,pid.
4. The ball is in your court now: you can do (almost) anything you want having full control over the filesystem and the user's requests